# Live blogging plugins?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

What do you all use for live blogging?

I've found [Live Blogging](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/live-blogging/) by Chris Northwood (more than I need) and [Twitter LiveBlog](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-liveblog/) by Mashuqur Rahman (I want it to stay within WordPress).  Are these really the only two games in town?

Comment: "What do you all use" and similar questions of a community nature should be marked as wikis.  You're not looking for a singular "best" answer here ...

Comment: *@gabrielk* - Can you explain what feature set you'd like to see? Since I don't live blog I really don't know what you might need but I am good at writing plugins... :)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - It's really just a question to see what's out there without re-inventing the wheel.  Doesn't seem like there's much.

Comment: Gotcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote my own Liveblogging platform, which turned out to be very simple to do indeed. Sadly, it's not ready for release yet.

In practice, all you need is a page with a form which writes to a database. Now; liveblogs tend to get hammered, so I created a page which used my templates as a flat file (so no database calls).

Whenever I updated the liveblog with another entry, it wrote it to a flat file, and it showed the flat file to the user.

Rather simple, but brutally fast. Stood up to very high traffic on [a small tech site you may have heard of](http://t3.com).

Comment: Hey, an answer!